# Как убрать лишние символы из переменной в BAT файле?

Tags: windows, bat

Есть файл со строками:

> // ...
>   // ...
>   //
>
> // ...
>
> 'r3690'

Мне нужно прочитать последнюю строку, что успешно делает:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in (myfile.inc) do set "xprvar=%%i"
```

В переменной `xprvar` остается `'r3690'`

Теперь мне нужно обрезать первый и последний символы `'`. Как это сделать в BAT файле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно выполнить строку:

```
SET verinfo2=%verinfo:'=%
```

Которая заменит `'` на пусто. В итоге остается нужная строка.